# ingresar datos a mysql con formulario

Tags: php, mysqli

hace poco tiempo publique la misma pregunta pero pasa que ha dejado de funcionar!
estoy tratando ingresar datos a una tabla en MySql. 
pero recibo este error:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: username in    H:\SERVER\htdocs\SITIO2\2\content\control_register_user.php on line 22

 Notice: Undefined variable: apellido in H:\SERVER\htdocs\SITIO2\2\content\control_register_user.php on line 22

 Notice: Undefined variable: email in H:\SERVER\htdocs\SITIO2\2\content\control_register_user.php on line 22

 Notice: Undefined variable: telefono in H:\SERVER\htdocs\SITIO2\2\content\control_register_user.php on line 22

 Notice: Undefined variable: usuario in H:\SERVER\htdocs\SITIO2\2\content\control_register_user.php on line 22

  Notice: Undefined variable: password in H:\SERVER\htdocs\SITIO2\2\content\control_register_user.php on line 22


Success
```

el archivo es el siguiente:

si saben como hacerlo en PHP7?

es que me he descargado la ultima versión de XAMPP  y trae esta version de PHP

este es el archivo encargado de insertar todo en MySQL.

Quisiera tambien implementar algun control que diga que el usuario ingresado ya existe(si es que existe!)

no quiero abusar de ustedes pero si me ayudan con algun control para el largo de la password, que pida ingresar alguna mayuscula, seria explendido.

muchas gracias de antemano!!

control_register_user.php:

```
      session_start();

      <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>

      <h1>Control Register Usuario</h1>

    <?php
   define ("MYSQLUSER", "jolunavi");
   define ("MYSQLPASS", "688200");
   define ("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
   define ("MYSQLDB", "msf");
   if ($coneccion = @new mysqli (HOSTNAME, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB));

if (isset($_REQUEST['user_nombre']) && isset($_REQUEST['user_apellido']) && isset($_REQUEST['user_email']) && isset($_REQUEST['user_telefono']) && isset($_REQUEST['user_usuario']) && isset($_REQUEST['user_password']) && isset($_REQUEST['user_token']))
{
#Asignar a las variable
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_nombre']) ? $_REQUEST['user_nombre'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_apellido']) ? $_REQUEST['user_apellido'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_email']) ? $_REQUEST['user_email'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_telefono']) ? $_REQUEST['user_telefono'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_usuario']) ? $_REQUEST['user_usuario'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_password']) ? $_REQUEST['user_password'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_token']) ? $_REQUEST['user_token'] : '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user_nombre,user_apellido,user_email,user_telefono,user_usuario,user_password) VALUES ('$username','$apellido','$email','$telefono','$usuario','$password')";
$query = mysqli_query($coneccion, $sql);
if (!$query) {
 echo "Error</br>";
 echo $sql;
 }
else {
 echo "Success";
 }
}
mysqli_close($coneccion);
?>

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Por favor podrían ayudarme a resolver?

aqui esta el formulario:

```
   <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>   
   <h1>Registrate</h1>
   <form action="control_register_user.php" method="post">
   <div class="maintform">
   <p class="formulario"><label for="name">Nombre:  </label> <input placeholder="Ejm: Juan" type="text" name="user_nombre" id="user_nombre"  /></p>
   <p class="formulario"><label for="name">Apellido:</label> <input placeholder="Ejm: Gutierrez" type="text" name="user_apellido" id="user_apellido"  /></p>
   <p class="formulario"><label for="name">email:   </label> <input placeholder="Ejm: ejemplo@gmail.com"type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email"  /></p>
   <p class="formulario"><label for="name">telefono:</label> <input placeholder="Ejm: 0931234567"type="text" name="user_telefono" id="user_telefono"  /></p>
   <p class="formulario"><label for="name">Usuario: </label> <input placeholder="Ejm: Pedrito1980"type="text" name="user_usuario" id="user_usuario"  /></p>
   <p class="formulario"><label for="name">Contrase&ntilde;a:</label> <input placeholder="Ejm: **************"type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password"/></p>
   <p class="formulario">
   <input class="ok" type="submit" name="testform" value="Terminado" />
   <input class="no_ok" type="reset" name="testform" value="Restablecer" />
   <input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancelar" onclick="window.location.href='../index.php';"/></p>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <?php 
     $salt = 'SomeSalt';
     $token = sha1(mt_rand(1,1000000) . $salt); 
     $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
     ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="user_token" id="user_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
   </div>
   </form>
   <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Muchas Gracias !!

Comment: Si puedes coloca el form en html con el que envias los datos mediante POST.

Comment: Una idea más _2016_ sería usar PDO.

Comment: Hola @Shaz, Sabrías explicarme como hacer?   ...sería de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Root", "MyRootPassword", "MyDbName");

        #Usa esta Verificacion
        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

            #Asignalas a una variable asi
            $usuario_login =$_POST['username'];
            $usuario_passwd =$_POST['password'];
            $usuario_nombre =$_POST['name'];
            $usuario_email =$_POST['email'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, name, email) VALUES    ('$usuario_login', '$usuario_passwd', '$usuario_nombre', ' $usuario_email')";

            $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            if (!$query) {
                echo "Error";
            } else {
                echo "Success";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Parametros vacios. Verifique POST del Form";
        }
```

Comment: lo siento amigo   ...me sigue dando error:

`Notice: Undefined index: username in ...\save-user.php on line 5`
Notice: Undefined index: password in ...\save-user.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: name in ...\save-user.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: email in ...\save-user.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: username in ...\save-user.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: password in ...\save-user.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: name in ...\save-user.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: email in ...\save-user.php on line 20`

Comment: probaste esa edición que le hice?. Si no comenta tu formulario a ver.

Comment: no me dá ningun error. pero no sube nada al database. que esta mal?

Comment: publica tu form a ver si los parámetros están llegando a su destino. Dice "Parametros vacios. Verifique POST del Form"

Comment: ok, modifiqué mi pregunta agregando el form y el archivo php actual.

Comment: prueba ahora debería funcionar

Comment: se detiene en: **Error**

Comment: En la estructura de la tabla tienes el campo id como autoincrement?. En el caso de que no sea así este cae en error ya que no se le asigna un valor por defecto

Comment: Funciona!    ...habian datos cruzados entre **$usuario_nombre =$_POST['name'];** y **$usuario_email =$_POST['email'];**     ...muchas gracias Christian Gimenez

Comment: Pon respondida esta pregunta para ayudar a la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Christian Gimenez

Answer (score 0):

No es error de mysql, 
es error de php donde usas **$_POST['username']** no te está llegando nada.

sugerencias,

1) para debug usa el metodo GET y verás en la barra de direcciones que es lo que te está llegando.
2) usa $_REQUEST en vez de $_POST funciona con GET y POST
3) no uses los valores directos porque te pueden hacer un sql injection

puedes usar una funcion para recuperar los datos del $_RQUEST algo como

```
function traerParametro( $nombre ){
  if ( array_key_exists( $nombre, $_REQUEST ) )
  {
    return funcionQueEviteSQLInjection( $_REQUEST[ $nombre ] );
  }
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No encuentro tu error, pero te paso un código que hice hace un tiempo, es php Orientado a objetos creo que es más fácil y eficiente. Espero te sirva

Clase encargada de gestionar las conexiones a la base de datos

class DB{

```
private $servidor; 
private $usuario; 
private $password; 
private $bd; 
private $link; 



//Constructor
function __construct(){
    $this->servidor = 'localhost';
    $this->usuario = 'root';
    $this->password = '';
    $this->bd = 'libreria';
    $this->conectar(); /*Al inicializar la clase ya estará conectada*/ 
} 

//Destructor   
function __destruct() {
    if (isset($this->link) && is_resource($this->link)) {
        mysql_close($this->link);
    }
}

/*Realiza la conexión a la base de datos.*/ 
private function conectar(){ 
  $this->link=mysql_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->password);
  if (!$this->link){
       die('Error de coneccion' . mysql_error());  
  }
  else{
        mysql_select_db($this->bd,$this->link); 
        mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
  }
}
```

Ejecuta una consulta regresa resultado

```
private function ExecuteQuery($query){
    $resultado = mysql_query($query,$this->link);
    if ($resultado)
        return $resultado;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Ejecuta una consulta  y no regresa resultado

```
private function ExecuteNonQuery($query){
    if ( (mysql_query($query,$this->link)) == true ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Insert sencillo con parametros

```
public function InsertarLibro($titulo, $paginas,$precio,$foto,$genero,$autor)
{
    $query="INSERT INTO libros(titulo,paginas,precio,foto,idGenero,idAutor) VALUES('$titulo', $paginas,$precio,'$foto',$genero,$autor)";
    $this->ExecuteQuery($query);
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    return $id;
}
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

El error te está diciendo que las variables no están definidas y en el código php está a la vista el problema, todas los valores los estás grabando en la misma variable `$nombre`

```
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_nombre']) ? $_REQUEST['user_nombre'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_apellido']) ? $_REQUEST['user_apellido'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_email']) ? $_REQUEST['user_email'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_telefono']) ? $_REQUEST['user_telefono'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_usuario']) ? $_REQUEST['user_usuario'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_password']) ? $_REQUEST['user_password'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_REQUEST['user_token']) ? $_REQUEST['user_token'] : '';
```

No estás definiendo las otras variables. Por otro lado te recomiendo que si recibes los datos por POST entonces los obtengas a través de `$_POST`

-------------------------------------------------------      EDIT:     -------------------------------------------------------

@jolunavi, el problema es que estas usando unos nombres de variables para obtener los datos del POST y otros nombres de variables en los VALUES al momento de insertar.

Si usas estos nombres de variables:

```
        $nombre =$_POST['user_nombre'];
        $apellido =$_POST['user_apellido'];
        $email =$_POST['user_email'];
        $telefono =$_POST['user_telefono'];
        $usuario =$_POST['user_usuario'];
        $password =$_POST['user_password'];
```

Entonces debes corregir cambiando esta línea:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user_nombre,user_apellido,user_email,user_telefono,user_usuario,user_password) VALUES ('$username','$apellido','$email','$telefono','$usuario','$password')";
```

Por esta:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user_nombre,user_apellido,user_email,user_telefono,user_usuario,user_password) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$email','$telefono','$usuario','$password')";
```

Debes revisar muy bien los nombres de los campos, el orden, y evitar trocar las variables.

-------------------------------------------------------      EDIT 2       ------------------------------------------------------

gracias Adres,

tenias razon, era esa variable que daba problemas

solucionado asi:

```
      <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
      <h1>Control Register Usuario</h1> 
      <?php 
       if (isset($_POST['user_nombre']) && isset($_POST['user_apellido']) && isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['user_telefono']) && isset($_POST['user_usuario']) && isset($_POST['user_password']) && isset($_POST['user_token']))
       {      
       # Asigno a una variable asi:
    if (!empty($nombre =$_POST['user_nombre']));
      if (!empty($apellido =$_POST['user_apellido']));
      if (!empty($email =$_POST['user_email']));
      if (!empty($telefono =$_POST['user_telefono']));
      if (!empty($usuario =$_POST['user_usuario']));
      if (!empty($password =$_POST['user_password']));
      if (!empty($password =$_POST['user_token']));
```

en esto tengo problemas

Como hago para poner un control?

osea que si el usuario ya existe   ...que me permita cambiar nombre de usuario o algo asi

```
        # creí poder solucionar asi, pero no funciona
        if ($_GET['user_usuario']) == $_POST['user_usuario'])
        {
          echo "usuario ya existente"
         }
```

continuacion......

```
    //imprimo las variables para saber si llegan o no
    $nombre =   $_POST['user_nombre'];     echo "nombre: ";   echo $_POST ['user_nombre'];   echo "<br />";
    $apellido = $_POST['user_apellido'];   echo "apellido: "; echo $_POST ['user_apellido']; echo "<br />"; 
    $email =    $_POST['user_email'];      echo "email: ";    echo $_POST ['user_email'];    echo "<br />";
    $telefono = $_POST['user_telefono'];   echo "telefono: "; echo $_POST ['user_telefono']; echo "<br />"; 
    $usuario =  $_POST['user_usuario'];    echo "usuario: ";  echo $_POST ['user_usuario'];  echo "<br />"; 
    $password = $_POST['user_password'];   echo "password: "; echo $_POST ['user_password']; echo "<br />"; 
    $token = $_POST['user_token'];         echo "token: ";    echo $_POST ['user_token'];    echo "<br />";
    echo "Los Archivos se reciben perfectamente. <br />";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (user_nombre,user_apellido,user_email,user_telefono,user_usuario,user_password) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$email','$telefono','$usuario','$password')";
      $query = mysqli_query($coneccion, $sql);
       if (!$query) {
       echo "Error</br>";
       echo $sql;
       }
       else {
       echo "Success";
       }
       }
       mysqli_close($coneccion);
       ?>
       <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Hola @Andres. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por lo que veo, esto ya está incluido en la respuesta aceptada hace más de 5 meses. Por otro lado, no veo ningún perjuicio en usar `$_REQUEST` permitiendo obtener los valores tanto por POST como por GET.